# Problem authenticating with username and password in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I recently started using Laravel 8 and I am trying to log in using username and email together but I do not know how to do this. In Laravel 7 I could use...

```php
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
        ? $this->username()
        : 'username';
    
    return [
        $field => $request->get($this->username()),
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
}
```

How can I log in using both username and password in Laravel 8 since there is no `LoginController` inside the `Auth` folder anymore?

Comment: side note: in 7 that controller isn't there by default either, you needed laravel/ui in 7 ... looks like for 8 they are pushing laravel/jetstream for the authentication scaffolding

Comment: @sta ```laravel/ui``` has been deprecated for v8

Answer (score 7):

**Solution working for Laravel-Jetstream**

**You can authenticate using `username or email` following this steps.**

**1.** Confirm login input field name (Let name is `identity`)

**2.** Change `config/fortify.php`

```
'username' => 'email' to  'username' => 'identity'
```

**3.** Added following authentication code in your `app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php` file inside **boot** method

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (LoginRequest $request) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->identity)
                ->orWhere('username', $request->identity)->first();

            if (
                $user &&
                \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
            ) {
                return $user;
            }
        });
```

> [Note] Please use those classes

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
```

**#For register username**

**1.** Add input in your `register.blade.php`

```
<div class="mt-4">
            <x-jet-label for="username" value="{{ __('User Name') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="username" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="username" :value="old('username')" required autofocus autocomplete="username" />
</div>
```

**2.** Add `username` in User model `$fillable` array list.

**3.** Finally change in `app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php` file

```
Validator::make($input, [
            ..........
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            .........
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
           .......
            'username' => $input['username'],
            .....
        ]);
    }
```

*Lets enjoy the authentication.*

Comment: Works great for registration! But can you please also tell, how it works for the login as well?

Comment: @treesoft already described here please follow the
 "You can authenticate using username or email following this steps" part.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my code you can log in with your username or email and you can do it with regular expressions in the validation part.**

```
public function login() {
    $credentials = $this->validate();
    
    if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $this->email, 'password' => $this->password), $this->remember_me) ||
         auth()->attempt(array('username' => $this->email, 'password' => $this->password), $this->remember_me)) {
        $user = User::where(["email" => $this->email])
            ->orWhere(["username" => $this->email])
        ->first();
        auth()->login($user, $this->remember_me);
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');        
    }
    else{
        return $this->addError('email', trans('auth.failed')); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Jetstream (available for Laravel 8) replaces Laravel Authentication UI which was available for previous Laravel versions. This means, for the authentication functionality you want, you have to install and use Jetstream.
To install Jetstream with composer, run the following command

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install
```

Then, depending on whether you want to use Livewire or Inertia, run one of the following two commands:

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
```

or

```
php artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

After that, then run

```
npm install && npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

Jetstream is ready for use.

Here is [Jetstream documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html) and a [quick tutorial](https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/what-is-laravel-jetstream-and-how-to-get-started).