# authenticating in laravel 8 with jetstream - username or email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am searching for a solution to change the standard Jetstream Auth to Auth with username or email. This means during the registration of the account you enter email or username (username is always required). In the login form you can enter username or email as your credentials. I have also changed in the profile settings to update also the username.

My actual problems are

1. during registration only with the username I get the error of the empty email field
   [registration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq0pA.jpg)
2. during login the username will be not a correct credential

I have changed everything similar to the post [Problem authenticating with username and password in Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63802266/problem-authenticating-with-username-and-password-in-laravel-8) but it doesn't work.

**1. change in `config/fortify.php`**

```
'username' => 'email' to 'username' => 'identity'
```

**2.added authentication code to `app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php` inside boot method**

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (LoginRequest $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->identity)
            ->orWhere('username', $request->identity)->first();

        if (
            $user &&
            \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
        ) {
            return $user;
        }
    });
```

and also added classes

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
```

**3. added username during register**
Add input field unter `register.blade.php`

```
<div class="mt-4">
            <x-jet-label for="username" value="{{ __('User Name') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="username" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="username" :value="old('username')" required autofocus autocomplete="username" />
</div>
```

and deleted the `required` from the email form field.

**4.add username to the User model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'username',
];
```

change in `app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php`

```
Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
    ])->validate();

    return User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'username' => $input['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
    ]);
```

**5. added username field to database**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('username')->nullable();
    });
```

Comment: Has someone an idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first case where username is required but email is optional, you will need to add `nullable` to your validation properties. Please check the docs on [optional fields](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).

For you second use case, `login.blade.php` the default input tag is `name="email"`. That means your condition will be
`$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->orWhere('username', $request->email)->first();`

Check [Customizing User Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication) on Laravel Fortify.